Why does moving a variable into a spawned thread pass the borrow checker even when not copied? Doesn't that mean it uses a pointer to the original?
I have this code but I do not understand why it compiles:
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;
struct State {
    value: u32,
}

impl State{
    pub fn new() -> State{
        State{ value: 0 }
    }
}

fn main() {
    run_thread();
    for i in 1..10 {
        println!("hi number {i} from the main thread!");
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(300));
    }
}

fn run_thread(){
    let state = State::new();

    thread::spawn(|| {
        let mut state = state;
        for i in 1..10 {
            state.value = i;
            println!("hi number {i} from the spawned thread!");
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(300));
        }
    });
}

As far as I understand it the variable state in run_thread() is allocated on the stack. Then it is moved in the closure and since it does not implement the Copy trait under the hood there will be just a pointer passed. But when run_thread() returns the stackframe will be destroyed, but the thread will still access the memory at that location and will corrupt the stackframe of any new called function.
Is this really the case? If not, what did I get wrong?

The capture does what it has to do:  https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/fn/closures/capture.html


Then it is moved in the closure and since it does not implement the copy trait under the hood there will be just a pointer passed.

This is incorrect. When a value is moved, the actual data (of the struct or whatever) is moved. Before the closure is constructed, the State is in a stack variable; after, it is in the closure. There is no pointer, so the closure does not borrow anything.
If you deleted the line let mut state = state; then the closure doesn't need to move, and would instead borrow state (or more precisely, it would borrow state.value), i.e. contain a pointer.

So moving means to (shallow) copy the struct from one memory location to another ?
Like e.g C# copies structs (value types) when they are assigend or passed to functions, just that in rust, the compiler makes sure, that the "old location" cannot be acessed anymore ?

"If you deleted the move keyword" - I don't see a move keyword in the OP's code. Is it implicit?

@Gerhard77 Yes, exactly, a Rust move is a “shallow copy” of the value, and comes with the additional rule that old location is unusable (unless the type implements Copy).

@Bergi Whoops, I read too fast. Fixed. In this case, let mut state = state; forces the move.
